# Salvar mesmo objeto múltiplas vezes

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa-2.0, glassfish

**Solução:** setar id = null

O código salva 10 vezes se rodar no servidor Tomcat, mas se rodar no Glassfish só adiciona uma vez.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>entities.Secao</class>
    <class>entities.Funcionario</class>
    <class>entities.Unidade</class>
    <class>entities.Patrimonio</class>
    <class>entities.Descricao</class>
    <class>entities.Classificacao</class>

    <validation-mode>AUTO</validation-mode>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/patrimonio" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

```
public void save() {
    int i = 0;
    EntityManager em = JpaUtil.getEntityManager();

    while (i < 10) {
        em.merge(item);         
        i = i + 1;          
    }
    item = new Item();      
}
```

Classe JPAUtil:

```
package persistence;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.hibernate.Session;

public class JpaUtil {

    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "default";

    private static ThreadLocal<EntityManager> manager = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();

    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

    private JpaUtil() {
    }

    public static boolean isEntityManagerOpen() {
        return JpaUtil.manager.get() != null && JpaUtil.manager.get().isOpen();
    }

    public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        if (JpaUtil.factory == null) {
            JpaUtil.factory = Persistence
                    .createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        }
        EntityManager em = JpaUtil.manager.get();
        if (em == null || !em.isOpen()) {
            em = JpaUtil.factory.createEntityManager();
            JpaUtil.manager.set(em);
        }
        return em;
    }

    public static void evictCache(EntityManager em, String region) {
        ((Session) em.getDelegate()).getSessionFactory().getCache()
                .evictQueryRegion(region);
    }

    public static void closeEntityManager() {
        EntityManager em = JpaUtil.manager.get();
        if (em != null) {
            EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
            if (tx.isActive()) {
                tx.commit();
            }
            em.close();
            JpaUtil.manager.set(null);
        }
    }

    public static void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
        closeEntityManager();
        JpaUtil.factory.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Erick, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Seu problema ocorre na mesma base de dados? Você verificou se as queries gerada tanto no Tomcat quanto no Glassfish são iguais? Poderia postá-las?

Comment: E coloque tambem o codigo do JpaUtil. A proposito: "salva" significa "cria um registro", ou em ambos casos apenas um registro é criado, mas salvo 10 vezes em um, e apenas um em outro?

Comment: @jpkrohling No tomcat ele cria 10 registros com ids diferentes no banco de dados e no Glassfish apenas um. Todo o código está aqui: https://github.com/erickdeoliveiraleal/sispatri

Comment: Por mais que o código possa parecer interessante, é prática do StackOverflow colocar o código pertinente na questão. O motivo é que, para alguém que está tentando ajudar, fica difícil achar os trechos de código e/ou ter uma visão completa do código em apenas alguns minutos.

Comment: @jpkrohling Postei a JPAUtil, talvez te ajude olhar aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421261/save-same-object-multiple-times ... Mas até agora não consegui mesmo usando em.persist

Comment: Creio que o problema seja com o transaction-type. Tente usar JTA, desta forma: **<persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="JTA">** Você pode dar uma olhadinha neste tutorial, creio que ajude: [link](http://sombriks.wordpress.com/2012/06/02/usando-jpa-2-e-jstl-no-tomcat-7/)

Answer (score 2):

Já tive esse mesmo problema algumas vezes no passado. E já consegui resolvê-lo.

A ideia é que cada requisição utilize um novo `EntityManager` para si.

O que acontece é que o seu `EntityManager` tem um escopo de thread, afinal ele é mantido em uma variável `ThreadLocal`. No entanto, escopo de thread não é a mesma coisa de escopo de requisição e é aí que o seu negócio fura. O container de aplicação reutiliza threads entre uma requisição e outra e como resultado uma requisição pode receber um `EntityManager` poluído com dados de cache de alguma requisição anterior, e pior, isso tende a ser bastante aleatório e não-determinístico.

Assim, você **SEMPRE** tem que limpar o `EntityManager` antes de usá-lo em qualquer requisição para evitar que este esteja poluído:

```java
 EntityManager em = ...;
 em.clear();
```

E você deve garantir que na sua aplicação, logo no início de cada requisição, antes de fazer qualquer outra coisa, que o `EntityManager` esteja limpo.

Já fui mordido por este problema algumas vezes no passado, hoje estou vacinado. Este é um erro comum de se cometer.

Ok, mas e porque funciona no tomcat e não no glassfish? A resposta disso é que eles gerenciam o pool de threads de maneiras distintas, e o código está errado nos dois: Se você rodar isso 10000 vezes, você vai forçar o tomcat a também reutilizar threads e também vai dar errado.

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente, não consigo dar uma explicação precisa sobre o que está acontecendo. Talvez o melhor seja fazer uma sessão de depuração, especialmente no JpaUtil.

Meu palpite: o Tomcat retorna sempre 10 sessões novas, enquanto que o Glassfish retorna sempre a mesma sessão. Como o objeto que você está tentando salvar está na sessão do Glassfish, as chamadas subsequentes são ignoradas, já que a finalização da sessão acontece no fim do request. Já no Tomcat, um novo objeto seria persistido a cada chamada, já que a sessão nova não sabe nada sobre o objeto que está sendo persistido. O esperado, pelo que pude ver no código, é ter *um* registro no banco de dados.

Mas vou aproveitar a resposta e dar uma ou outra dica sobre JPA em aplicações web.

- Tente usar o provedor JPA do seu "container". Se você precisa de JPA, então, é melhor usar um container que já provê uma implementação (Glassfish, JBoss AS/Wildfly, ...).
- Consuma o EntityManager provido pelo container. O jeito mais fácil é usando CDI e injetando um @PersistenceContext.
- Não especifique os detalhes de conexão diretamente no seu persistence.xml . O melhor é configurar um DataSource no seu container, e apontar este recurso em seu persistence.xml. Não que seja errado, mas você terá vários benefícios ao fazer isso. Por exemplo, você começará a fazer uso de um connection pooling sem fazer esforço nenhum.

A forma que você está utilizando o JPA é completamente defasado para aplicações web modernas (ie: mais novas do que uns 5 anos). A forma que você utiliza é recomendada somente para aplicações não-web, mas infelizmente vários tutoriais ensinam desta forma, já que é mais "prático" do que explicar como fazer as configurações necessárias.

Existem vários tutoriais na Web de como fazer a coisa certa, mas talvez possa dar uma olhada neste pequeno projeto para ter um exemplo no Wildfly:

[Exemplo de persistence.xml](https://github.com/jpkrohling/cascaio/blob/master/backend/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml)

[Exemplo de "JpaUtil"](https://github.com/jpkrohling/cascaio/blob/master/backend/src/main/java/com/cascaio/backend/v1/control/ApplicationResources.java#L20)

[Exemplo de como obter um EntityManager](https://github.com/jpkrohling/cascaio/blob/master/backend/src/main/java/com/cascaio/backend/v1/boundary/referencedata/ExchangeRateService.java#L40).

[Como configurar um data source para Wildfly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/DataSource+configuration) fica como exercício de casa :-)

Answer (score 1):

Nesse trecho de código, você já tentou utilizar o método persist() ao invés de merge()?

O método merge() possui um propósito diferenciado de persist(), já que persist() de fato insere o registro na base de dados.

Obtido no java doc Java EE 6

> void persist(java.lang.Object entity)
>
> Make an instance managed and persistent.

É bem provavél que a chamada de merge() em diferentes containers resulte em diferentes resultados. Em função dos provedores, gerenciamento de transação, etc.

```
public void save() {
    int i = 0;
    EntityManager em = JpaUtil.getEntityManager();

    while (i < 10) {
        //em.merge(item);         
        em.persist(item);
        i = i + 1;          
    }
    item = new Item();      
}
```